# Android & cut (remove) shape from bitmap

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

How do you cut (remove) a section from a bitmap???
I want that section/shape to be removed.. leave transparent in place of section..
Say shape is cercle or square..

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want to do this in code? What have you tried?

Comment: i have no idea how (yet.. thats why i have stackoverflow account).. i used only image composing so far.. & yes Java code..want to use it in some android app

Comment: Linear Algebra.I can't provide you code but I do know that this is a simple algrebra/geometry problem. You can get the metrics from a touch event to form an array of ints corresponding to the user touching and dragging. Then use that array to remove the same size and shape area from the bitmap.

Comment: Just draw a clear circle onto the canvas. Simple

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>You should be able do this with a Porter-Duff color filter and a `Canvas`:</strike>

```
public void punchHole(Bitmap bitmap, float cx, float cy, float radius) {
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new PorderDuffColorFilter(0, PorderDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    c.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);
}
```

Well, that was wrong. However, using a Porter-Duff transfer mode does work:

```
public void punchHole(Bitmap bitmap, float cx, float cy, float radius) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);
}
```

(The bitmap passed as an arg needs to be modifiable, of course.)

Comment: nothing happened: i tested with all modes, from android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR to the last one.. & no good result.. for CLEAR actually nothing happens.. for some of the other modes i end up with a black cercle.

Comment: did some more googleing & "AlphaComposite.CLEAR: Nothing will be drawn in the combined image".. so point deducted :P

Comment: @pulancheck1988 - That's odd. I'll have to check it out. According to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html), `PorderDuff.Mode.CLEAR` is supposed to produce color 0 and alpha 0 as the output. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10495105/535871) seems to confirm that it will indeed behave this way in Android. The [JavaDocs for AlphaComposite.CLEAR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html#CLEAR) say the same thing.

Comment: @pulancheck1988 - Okay, like you say, a Porter-Duff color filter doesn't work. However, using a `PorterDuffXferMode` does work. I updated my answer to show the code that's needed.

Comment: I can't get `paint.setXferMode(new PorterDuffXferMode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));` to work. 1) I set the background layout to a bright green color. 2) in my custom View class, I'll use the paint with Mode.Clear to "cut shapes" out of a rectangle. 3) the result is that my rectangle sits on a bright green background and all the shapes, that are supposed to be cut out of the rectangle, show up as pitch black!! (I expected the background green to "shine through" the areas that are supposed to be cut out. :-(

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere - I'd have to know more details about what you're doing. The best thing you can do, I think, is to create a separate question and show all the relevant code, explain what you expect it to do (you can reference this thread to clarify), and describe (perhaps with a picture) what is happening instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bitmap.setPixel(x,y,Color) function to set the desired pixels to transparent

for example:

```
Bitmap bmp = ...;
bmp.setPixel (100,100,Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

for the pixel at x/y offset 100,100.  Though you'll find this potentially slow to do this on many pixels...

Comment: Ha.. this works..tested on a rect 20x30.. but there must be something already out there so i dont do my math on pixels directly..

Comment: if tried with all combinations of FillType & Op:                                                Path p1 = new Path();
  p1.setFillType(FillType.WINDING);
  p1.addCircle(60, 60, 20, Direction.CCW);
  canvas.clipPath(p1, Op.INTERSECT); ... and nothing

Answer (score 0):

Did you try drawing a circle with a transparent color,
ARGB = 0,0,0,0 ?

Comment: exactly, painting with a transparent color has no effect.